# Excel set/get cell color but for multiple cells on same step (different color to a different cell)

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

**Preface:**
I can set/get a cell range value2 member at the same step passing/getting 2d array:

```
range.Value2 = some2dArray;
var another2dArray = range.Value2 as Object[,];
```

**The problem:**
But what about `Range.Interior.Color` member?
How can I retrieve/assign cells' colors as/with a 2d array?
`Range.Interior.Color` returns null to me when I trying to get its value for multiple cells as a 2d array:

```
var thisAppearsToBeNull = someRange.Interior.Color as double[,];
var thisAlsoAppearsToBeNull = someRange.Interior.Color as Object[,];
```

Would be great if I could do this correctly without iterating the whole range myself (I don't care if some underlying implementation of Excel would do it; as far as I understand, Excel would do it much faster anyway).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is still relevant, but not so much. I found out that getting/setting colors via iterating the whole range in C# code is fast enough, but in case of setting colors, it causes little but annoying freezes later, when a user accesses the worksheet to "see" those colored cells.

```
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Interior.Color = (object)colors[row-1, col-1];
```